# How to run corda node on production

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, devops, corda

Hi I want to run Corda code on production environment.
As of now i am running this via commands and getting this:-
! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.

my commands are

cd /var/www/Menkymac-Backend/CordaService/build/nodes/Menkymac/ && sudo java -Dcapsule.jvm.args="-Xmx700m" -jar corda.jar

cd /var/www/Menkymac-Backend/CordaService/build/nodes/Notary && sudo java -Dcapsule.jvm.args="-Xmx700m" -jar corda.jar

cd /var/www/Menkymac-Backend/CordaService && sudo ./gradlew runIssuerServer

So please let me know if there is any alternative for this for Production.

Answer (score 3):

The message is because you are running your node is dev mode. By default, Corda nodes run in dev mode unless otherwise specified. Dev mode can be turned off by setting the devMode flag to false.

You can learn more about devmode and other node configurations here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/corda-configuration-file.html

You might also want to take a look at how to properly deploy a Corda node on a server:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/deploying-a-node.html

Also for production you should generally setup a dynamic compatibility zone rather than using the local bootstrapped network, Read more about it here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/setting-up-a-dynamic-compatibility-zone.html#setting-up-a-dynamic-compatibility-zone